# How to Automate UI, API, Performance & Security testing using a single Framework?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, security

How to Automate UI, API, Performance & Security testing using a single Framework. One test case should check all these things. Any suggestions?

Comment: `One test case should check all those things`- why do you want to do this?

Comment: This is an unrealistic goal for an undefined objective.

Comment: Why do you want only one framework ?

Comment: One test case will check security, performance and functionality? Can you give a real example of such case?

Answer (score 2):

My solution is to pick a language, for example Ruby (a good choice imho) or Java or C# as the 'framework' for your solutions (I'm avoiding the word `framework` lately though, badly abused).

Then select tools based on that toolset, for example, for ruby: cucumber, rspec, minitest.

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose a performance testing tool which supports all aforementioned requirements, for example take a look at [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/):

1. UI tests can be integrated via [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/)
2. API testing is naturally supported via [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, see [Building a WebService Test Plan](http://people.apache.org/~mkostrze/jmeter-docs/docs/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html) user manual entry for details.
3. You can use JMeter for Security Testing as well, see [Security Testing With JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/security-testing-with-jmeter-learn-how) article for several use cases
4. And last but not least you can kick off any external command or program via [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) so theoretically you can integrate anything into JMeter test.

Comment: +1 for jmeter.  You can use jmeter for functional testing.  You can schedule quick diagnostic checks to ensure that your website and/or API is up and running.  One of my favorite things about jmeter is that you can setup an API test and use the exact same test for performance testing your API.  Then there is the JSR223 Processor, where you can write custom scripts using your favorite language.